# Answers to locked community wiki questions?

Tags: support

[What kind of mail server do you use?](https://serverfault.com/questions/722/what-kind-of-mail-server-do-you-use) is a locked community wiki question/post.  What combination of features prevents me from modifying/deleting my [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/722/what-kind-of-mail-server-do-you-use/4967#4967)?  Is there a way to flag a locked question like this for moderator attention?  I would have done that, but the obvious way (flag link) is missing.

Qmail was on the way out in 2009 (Some would argue it was already dead).  Personally, I now think things are to the point where there should be no new users of Qmail.  If I can't edit that into my answer, how do I request it be nuked from orbit?

Comment: Side note to SysAdmin's general Answer, I blew away your Answer. So you're all set.

Comment: Personally I now think things are to the point where there should be no users of Qmail and DJB should be sent into exile for crimes against humanity. But I'm an extremist :-)

Comment: `how do I request it be nuked from orbit?`  By asking the question here, it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locked questions are locked for a reason. The mod-staff felt that a particular question and answer-set had merit sufficient to save it from deletion, but not enough to leave it open. Because of that, the only way to modify such questions is to do exactly what you did: Open a Meta question for community debate.

Comment: Might a mod flag have achieved the same goal?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers If it's available, which I'm not sure of. I, of course, see that button but I can't tell what the visibility is.

Comment: @MarkJohnson It's there to indicate that this used to be a commwiki back before the  question was frozen in a block of ice.